# Access files in the Gradle dist directory

Tags: java, gradle, software-distribution, file-access

Working on a Gradle project and I want to have loose data files so that more can be loaded on the fly.

I need to load these files from the Java application the Gradle project is made for.

How would I load files that are placed in the src/dist directory so they are still accessible when the program is packaged?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out a method myself.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

gets the directory the program was launched from.

In a Gradle packaged project, that's the bin folder.  You can just move up a directory from there.

Running it from an IDE it's the root project folder which is harder to deal with.  A better method would be nice to have, but this works for now.